# Grey scale part of image

Tags: android, picasso, android-bitmap, grayscale

I am downloading an image via Picasso and grey-scaling it.

Is there any way to grey-scale only a part of the image?
In other words I only want to scale the left x% of it.

I am grey-scaling using the official example [official example](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso/GrayscaleTransformation.java)

What I can't figure out is how to grey scale a part of it.
I specifically want to grey-scale the right hand part.

The idea is to use it as a progress percentage. If you have completed 35% of the required action then 35% will be in teh actual colour and the remaining 65% greyed out.

I thought of maybe cropping the "noise" mask by the percentage I want but can't figure out how to then use it as a partial mask right justified (so that the left part of the image is untouched).

Comment: If you just copy and modify the code, easiest would be to use `canvas.setClipRect` which will ignore everything done to the canvas outside of it.

Comment: I don't follow. Wouldn't that completely clip out part of the image? I need the left part to be the same as the original with the right part greyed out.

Comment: clip rect will only allow drawing where you specify to. everything else will be as it was

Comment: I tried adding canvas.clipRect(canvas.getWidth()/2, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()) before drawRect but I still get it all greyed out.

Comment: I know it is too late to comment here. but for new user this is working fine.what problem you were getting i don not know or other user can check below link
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-rotation-and-transformation/